# Extract data with a certain column value in r

Tags: r

I have a dataframe dat1 in r and I would like to create another dataframe for all data from dat1, where column2 has a certain value.

So for example:

dat1 = [ 1  2  3
             4  5  6 ]

dat2 should contain all data where dat1$column2 == 2.

How could I do this?

Comment: I would use dplyr filter(). Like...dat2<-dat2 %>% filter(column 2 == 2).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will use the built functions for filtering data frames.

```
dat1 = data.frame(col=c(1,2,3,4,5,6))
dat2 = dat1[dat1$col ==2,]
```

dat2 will be returned as a single value instead of as a data frame.

Answer (score 2):

The filter function in tidyverse will do this for you:

```
# setup 
library(tidyverse)
dat1 <- data.frame('x' = c(1:5), 'y' = rnorm(5,0,1))

# solution
dat2 <- dat1 %>% filter(x == 2)
```

Note the `%>%` is a "pipe" telling it to feed `dat1` into the `filter()` function, taking the rows of `dat1` where `x` is 2, and store them as `dat2`

There are some other solutions such as indexing

```
dat1[dat1[,'x'] == 2,]
```

And `subset()` function

```
subset(dat1, x == 2)
```

Comment: Thanks! And how can I use the filter() function with columns?

Comment: Does this not do exactly what you want? It does the same as the other answer... a bit strange to accept this answer and then change to the other when it does the same, and then ask for something else...